# Small bash script to enhance virtual environments on directory navigation

Tags: bash, console

Ages ago I made a small `bash` script which would add a command `cdp`, standing for "change directory - project".

What it did was simple, it added all folders in `~/projects` as autocompletion and CD'd me into them using only the project folder's name.

Over time I switched to a different company where I started working with Python, thus needing virtual environments not to mess up my workstation, which led me to adding more functionalities to the script.

I rarely use bash to do anything, rather using Python or even PHP for simple CLI tasks. I was hoping for some input regarding my first ever bash script, though, so I can keep my terminal scripts in its native language.

I think some improvements could be the way I name and call functions, and the newly added command should probably be something other than an alias.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

funcCheckVirtualEnvironment()
{
    if [ -d "venv/" ]; then
        read -p "A virtual environment was found for this project, would you like to execute the activation script? [y/n]" -n 1 -r
        echo
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
            source venv/bin/activate
            if [ -e "requirements.txt" ]; then
                read -p "PyPi requirements were found, would you like to install any uninstalled packages? [y/n]" -n 1 -r
                echo
                if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
                    pip install -r requirements.txt
                fi
            fi  
        fi
    fi      
}

funcCDP()
{

    # Add more flags in future, maybe
    case "$1" in
    "-r" )
        funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
        return 0 ;;
    esac

    if [ -d ~/projects/$1 ]; then
        cd ~/projects/$1;
        funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
    else
        echo "Directory $1 does not exist!"
    fi

}

funcCD()
{
    if [ $1 == "-"] || [ -d $1 ]; then
        command cd "$@"
        if [ -d "venv/" ]; then
            funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
        fi
    else
        echo "No such file or directory: $1"
    fi
}

_cdp()
{
        local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W '$(\ls ~/projects)' -- $cur) )
}
complete -F _cdp cdp
alias cdp=funcCDP
alias cd=funcCD
```

Comment: Have you tried `virtualenvwrapper` for python? It has an awesome feature [`setvirtualenvproject`](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_ref.html#setvirtualenvproject) which binds any project/directory to an existing/active virtualenv; and later you can `cdproject` to switch to that.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I haven't and will try it out at home, though I am reluctant to use a different virtual environment manager at work than the rest of my co-workers. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: `virtualenvwrapper` is a friendlier (read humane) version for `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No shebang

It doesn't make sense to execute this as a program - it's intended to be sourced into an interactive shell.  So we shouldn't have the `#!` line.

## Quote expansions

`$1` could expand into multiple words here:

```
    if [ -d ~/projects/$1 ]; then
        cd ~/projects/$1;
```

and here:

```
    if [ $1 == "-"] || [ -d $1 ]; then
```

## Send errors to stderr

```
    echo "Directory $1 does not exist!" >&2
    #                                   ^^^ IMPORTANT
```

## Don't ask questions when used non-interactively

`funcCheckVirtualEnvironment` can misbehave when standard input is not a terminal.  We should test that case and return early:

```
test -r "venv/bin/activate" || return 0;
if ! test -t 0
then echo "Warning: not activating virtual environment" >&2
     return 0   # or 1 if this should be a failure
fi
read -p "Execute this project's activation script? [y/N]" -n 1 -r; echo
[[ REPLY =~ [Yy] ]] || return 0;
```

I've transformed some of the other `if` and `else` above into early returns, to reduce the nesting depth - I find that easier to read.  Also, I've capitalised `N` in the prompt, to provide the usual indication of the default.  And we know that `$REPLY` is a single character, so we can lose the anchors.

## Let `cd` do its own checking instead

There's a possible race between checking for the existence of a directory and actually changing into it, so it's easier and safer to simply check whether `cd` succeeded:

```
command cd "$@" && test -d 'venv' && funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
```

This also allows `cd` to produce the error message (in the user's preferred `$LANG`uage).

## Consider the exit status of the command

If we `cd` but there's no `venv` directory at the destination, that should be considered a success:

```
command cd "$@" || return $?
if test -d "venv"
then funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
else true
fi
```

Actually, there's no need to check for the existence of `venv/`, given that funcCheckVirtualEnvironment does that itself, and should succeed if it's not present:

```
command cd "$@" && funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
```

Similarly, in `cdp -r`, instead of `return 0`, a plain `return` is better, as that will result in the return value of the last executed command (`funcCheckVirtualEnvironment` in this case).

## Use standard directory completion

It's bad practice to parse the output of `ls`.  Instead, we can ask `compgen` to give us directory names; we can eliminate absolute paths and subdirectories by excluding anything containing `/`:

```
_cdp()
{
        COMPREPLY=( $(cd ~/projects && compgen -X '*/*' -d $2) )
}
```

---

## My version

```
funcCheckVirtualEnvironment()
{
    test -r 'venv/bin/activate' || return 0;
    if ! test -t 0
    then
        # Not a terminal - don't ask questions
        echo "Warning: not activating virtual environment" >&2
        return 0   # or 1 if this should be a failure
    fi

    read -p "Execute this project's activation script? [y/N]" -n 1 -r; echo
    [[ REPLY =~ [Yy] ]] || return 0;
    source venv/bin/activate || return $?
    
    test -e 'requirements.txt' || return 0;
    read -p "Install any missing PyPi packages? [y/N]" -n 1 -r; echo
    [[ REPLY =~ [Yy] ]] || return 0;
    pip install -r requirements.txt
}

funcCDP()
{
    # Add more flags in future, maybe
    case "$1" in
    "-r" )
        funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
        return
        ;;
    esac

    cd ~/projects/"$1" && funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
}

funcCD()
{
    command cd "$@" && funcCheckVirtualEnvironment
}

_cdp()
{
    COMPREPLY=( $(cd ~/projects && compgen -X '*/*' -d $2) )
}
complete -F _cdp cdp
alias cdp=funcCDP
alias cd=funcCD
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Quite a few of these tips will be very helpful in future bash scripts. I never knew of the `test` command, and going off of it's manpage I'll be using it a lot!

Comment: @Berry - I think you did already know about test (you have already been using it under its other name, `[`).  It's merely a matter of preference whether you call it `test` or `[`...`]`.